# AngularJS table orderBy checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, filter, sql-order-by

I want to sort a table when a checkbox is clicked and be able to filter the table also. The code below has been fixed and works now....

HTML

```
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in myArray | filter : name | orderBy : sortOrder">
      <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.age }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sortByName" ng-change="setSortOrder()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="name">
```

AngularJS

```
app.controller("myController", function($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.filterString = '';
    $scope.sortByName = false;
    $scope.sortOrder = '';

    $scope.setSortOrder = function()
    {
        if($scope.sortByName)
        {
            $scope.sortOrder = 'name';
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.sortOrder = '';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing telling your checkbox to call the controller method that selects the sort criteria when its checked status changes. You can do this by using the [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive. Try the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="sortByName" ng-change="setSortOrder()">
```

Comment: awesome, that's got the sort working, I'll have a play with the filter, thanks

Comment: Great!, glad I was able to help.